# Get a list of all wikipedia articles in certain language

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to get a list of all wikipedia articles in certain language. 
I tried to use wikipedia api (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php), but can't find filter by language (I found this parameter "converttitles", but it seems to convert titles to other variants if necessary, and I want to get all valuse in certain language.
Isn't there a better way to do it?

Comment: Uh, all articles in `en.wikipedia.org` are English? What do you want to filter for?

Comment: @Bergi - thanks you're right! I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: what action did you use to get the list?

Comment: @clankill3r I used action=query. See here for examples: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bergi comment: you can reach to every language by change the start of the url to include the two letter of the required language:
[your language].wikipedia.org/w/api.php

For example - hebrew api result will get from here: https://he.wikipedia.org/w/api.php